# $b\equiv a\mod pq\Leftrightarrow\ b\equiv a\mod p\text{ and }b\equiv a\mod q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given two primes $p$ and $q$, does this following equivalence hold? $$b\equiv a\mod pq\Leftrightarrow\ b\equiv a\mod p\text{ and }b\equiv a\mod q$$

I think "$\Leftarrow$" is true and follows from the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) although I am not sure how to properly use it. Regarding "$\Rightarrow$", however, I have no idea. It seems to be true although it feels wrong.

Comment: Hint: $b\equiv a\pmod {pq}$ if and only if $pq\mid b-a.$ This theorem only work if $p,q$ are *distinct* primes (or, more generally, are relatively prime.)

Comment: Ah, so obviously both $p$ and $q$ divide $b-a$ which yields $\Leftarrow$. And what about $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: Actually, that "obviously" goes the other way. It shows $\implies.$

Comment: Haha, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: The $\implies$ case goes for any $p,q$, prime or not. The other direction requires conditions on $p,q.$